# which algorithm to choose for object detection?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I am interested in detecting single object more precisely a fire extinguisher which has no inter class variability (all fire extinguisher looks same). However, The application is supposedly realtime i.e a robot is exploring the environment and whenever it sees the object of interest it should be able to detect it and give pixel coordinates of it.

My question is which algorithm will be good choice for this task?
1. Is this a classification problem and should we use features(sift/surf etc) + bow +svm?
2. some other solution (no idea yet).

Any kind of input will be appreciated. 
Thanks.
(P.S bear with me i am newbie to computer vision and stack over flow)

**update1:**
[image]

Height varies all are mounted on the wall but with different height. I tried with SIFT features and bow but it is expensive to extract bow descriptors in testing part. Moreover I have no idea how to locate the object(pixel coordinates) inside the image after its been classified positive.

**update 2:**

I finally used sift + bow + svm and am able to classify the object. But using this technique, i only get output interms of whether the object is present in the scene or not? 
How can i detect the object i.e getting the bounding box or centre of the object. what is the compatible approach with the above method for achieving these results.
Thank you all.

Comment: if there is enough structure/texture within the object, sift/surf and a database of different views of the object could do the job.

svm trained HoG descriptors are another recently widely used technique in science.

Comment: This highly depends on your data, For example color would be a big help. 3D features only work if your sensor has stereo vision. Height information could be used if all extinguishers are on the same level. Other features depend on how exactly your fire extinguishers look. Could you post some pictures of the fire extinguishers taken by your robot?

Comment: @Micka Are these techniques proved to be robust enough that suitable for real time systems? e.g I am interested in 5 to 7 fps.

Comment: @user3126137 robustness strongly depends on robustness of your feature extraction and the number of extractable features.

if you are able to compute SIFT/SURF features and descriptors in your realtime bound, most of the work is done. Since you only consider 1 kind of object, a database with maybe 100 images would be enough i guess. Time for comparing features depends on number of features.
I suggest just trying SIFT/SURF if it works, you can try improving speed.
Finding location within the image after successful recognition is be to compute a homography from matched feature correspondences

Comment: you might want to have a look at that openCV tutorial ;)
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Comment: @Micka Thanks. what will be img_object in my case? if i follow the tutorial you posted in the previous comment?

Comment: @Micka sorry for not understanding your comment first. so do you mean that I dont go for bow and svm rather just compute feature and descriptor for data base images and match them with query image descriptors in a loop? for whcih ever database image i find maximum score of matching i choose that one and draw matches or bounding box?

Comment: basically: yes
img_object is a sample image of your object. you will have to capture sample images from "each" side and "each" angle. you will have to find methods to not accept the "best" match but decide whether there isn't the object in the image at all (there is always a best match). it won't be trivial, but if SIFT is applicable here, it should be manageable.
Try the tutorial and decide whether SIFT/SURF are applicable.

Comment: Have you looked more in detail exactly what is taking too long? If it is the SURF/SIFT-steps, then there are other detectors/descriptors you can use.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I managed to test it and its giving me desire able speed now.But this is only classification and I have still no idea how to detect the object using after this step. by detection i mean bounding box and more precisely center of the object.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using color as the main feature to look for, and only try other features as needed. The fire extinguisher red is very distinctive, and should not occur too often elsewhere in an office environment. Other, more computationally expensive tests can then be performed only in regions of the right color.

Here is a good [tutorial for color detection](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.de/2010/09/object-detection-using-color-seperation.html) that also explains how to find good thresholds for your desired color.

I would suggest the following approach:

- denoise your image with a median filter
- convert the image to HSV format (Hue, Saturation, Value)
- select pixels close to that particular shade of red with InRange()
  Now you have a binary image image that contains only the pixels that are red.
- count the number of red pixels with CountNonZero()

  - If that number is too small, abort
- remove noise from the binary image by morphological opening / closing
- find contours of all blobs in your picture with findContours or the CvBlob library
- check if there are blobs of the correct width, correct height and correct width/height ratio
  since your fire extinguishers are vertical cylinders, the width/height ratio will be constant from every angle. The width and height will of course vary somewhat with distance to the camera.

  - if the width and height do not match, abort
- repeat these steps to find the black-colored part on the bottom of the extinguisher,

  - abort if there is no black region with correct width/height below the red region
- (perhaps also repeat these steps for the metallic top and the yellow rectangle)

These tests should all be very fast. If they are too slow, you could reduce the resolution of your input images.

Depending on your environment, it is possible that this is already a robust enough test. If not, you can proceed with sift/surf feature matching, but only in a small region around the blobs with the correct color. You also do not necessarily have to do that for each frame, each n-th frame should be be enough for confirmation.

Comment: *since your fire extinguishers are vertical cylinders, the width/height ratio will be constant from every angle* This is only true if you make assumptions on how the robot is moving relative to the extinguisher. Overall, your method requires quite a lot of assumptions on the environment, and will not be very robust.

Comment: @HannesOvrén I am assuming that the robot moves horizontally along the floor, and keeps its camera roughly aligned with the floor and that the extinguishers are hanging vertically on the wall at a height reachable by humans. I think that is a quite reasonable assumption, thought you could improve the margin of erro by testing the ratio of the minimal bounding rectangle instead. Overall I disagree with your conclusion that color-based recognition would not be robust in this case, but perhaps you may want to specify other assumptions or suggest a more suitable approach?

Comment: I agree that your assumption on movement is fine. It's just that you can still get perspective distorsions when, e.g. you get very close to the extinguisher. Basing it on color alone would mean that you make assumptions on lighting conditions, and that no other object with that color will ever show up. Also, the extinguisher is not only red, but has quite a lot of text, which means thresholding in a robust way and get a solid blob will likely be difficult. I don't have a better answer, because I am somewhat out of my comfort zone. I just wanted to give some perspectives on your answer :)

Comment: Ah well, I think most of the problems of false negatives can be solved by choosing the parameters with a large enough margin of error. For example while the width/height ratio can vary with perspective, the width should never be larger than the height; similar for color. Getting a solid blob may require some morphological opening. This way there is surely a chance for false positives (other red objects of roughly the right dimensions, with black bottoms), but those can be removed by further tests like SIFT *limited* to that region, so the performance should be less of a concern.

Comment: The approach is a bit too much ad-hoc for my taste, but I agree that it probably can be done. Guess we'll have to agree to disagree until someone tries an implementation ;)

Comment: I tried the method but its more naive approach and didnt get deired reults since I am looking for more generic one. However, I manage to classify the object using SIFt + SVM + BOW. Its working good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question .. but will still like to give my recommendation to use YOLO algorithm to solve this problem.
YOLO fits very well to this scenario.